# How to modify Android image downloader into AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, performance, android-asynctask, android-download-manager

Can someone give me hand. How can I re use the sample below using AsyncTask rather then the Try block.

As I just want to download a image from the Web save to SD and get the returned Stored path, so I can load it onto a imageView.

I am using a library https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap I have Circle Thumbnails ImageView. I can only change the image of this view by using a drawer image. That Why I am trying to save the image first then load onto this custom imageView

```
String filepath = "";
                    try
                    {   
                      URL url = new URL("http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg");
                      HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                      urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                      urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
                      urlConnection.connect();                  
                      File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
                      String filename="downloadedFile.png";   
                      Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename);
                      File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
                      if(file.createNewFile())
                      {
                        file.createNewFile();
                      }                 
                      FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                      InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                      int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                      int downloadedSize = 0;   
                      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                      int bufferLength = 0;
                      while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
                      {                 
                        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
                        Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
                      }             
                      fileOutput.close();
                      if(downloadedSize==totalSize) filepath=file.getPath();    
                    } 
                    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                    {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                      filepath=null;
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, "''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''");
                    Log.i("filepath:"," "+filepath) ;
                    //return filepath;
```

I get a NULL value for filepath

Comment: use the above code in asynctask's doInBackground() method

Comment: what issue you are getting using posted code?

Comment: I would highly suggest using an open source solution for downloading and displaying images in an `ImageView`. Check out Picasso: https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: use volley library --http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/

Comment: did you check about picasso?
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I just need a lightweight function to download only one image. with the sample below I get a Null value.

Comment: look at this: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/imageview/android-how-to-load-image-from-url-in-imageview/

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView mChart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
String URL = "http://www...anything ...";

mChart.setTag(URL);
new DownloadImageTask.execute(mChart);
```

The Task class:

```
public class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView imageView = null;

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
this.imageView = imageViews[0];
return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
}


private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
  ...
}
```